# CKEditor 4 Toolbar Dropdown in IE7

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg, fckeditor, internet-explorer-7

I am using ckeditor 4 for my project. The dropdown list in ckedior toolbar is not opening in IE7 where as it is opening fine in Chrome and Firefox. Any idea why?

Internet Explorer 7
[image: Internet Explorer]

Chrome
[image: Chrome]

Comment: see http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10189 maybe it is you case.

Answer (score 1):

Actual version of CKEditor I was using is 4.0.1.1. I reverted back to CKEditor 4.0 and it worked in IE7 as well. It seems there is some problem with version 4.0.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with IE9 downgraded to emulate IE7. Then I did not get a context menu.

By forcing the document mode to at least IE8 it worked as expected.

Comment: Tested for both v4.0.2 and v4.1

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue in a Symfony2 project.

Oddly I noticed that the dropdowns worked in the Symfony2 development environment, and discovered that they worked when the Sf2 debug bar was enabled.

I then did some inspection in chrome and found the CKEditor dropdown elements are in an iframe that's added as the last element in the body.

I then tried adding an empty div tag as the last element in the body (previously the last element was a script tag), and that fixed the problem.

So, add a plain, empty div tag as the last element of the body and the dropdowns are all ok.